# Ansibleでrootをdisableにした後に、playbookを再実行するとエラーが発生する場合の対処法

Tags: ansible

下記のような構成の時、最初に`root`ユーザーで、`deploy`ユーザを追加して、rootでのログインを禁止にした場合、どうやって冪等性を保つのがいいのでしょうか？
`ansible-playbook -i staging site.yml`みたいなコマンドの1回目は問題なく動作しますが、2回目はrootでログインできないので、エラーが発生します。この場合、色々なやり方（ファイルを分けるや、`--limit`するなど）があると思いますが、どうやるのが良いやり方なんでしょうか？

```
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: root
  port: 22
  roles:
    - something1

- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: deploy
  port: 10022
  roles:
    - something2
```

Answer (score 1):

playbook は、基本的に deploy ユーザーにしておいて、最初だけ root ユーザーで実行させるのが良い気がします。

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: deploy
  become: yes
  port: 10022
  tags: ['init']
  roles:
  - useradd_deploy
  - disable_root_user
  - sshd

- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: deploy
  port: 10022
  roles:
  - something2
```

１回目は、root で、port を 22 で init タグのみ実行

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --tags init -e ansible_ssh_user=root -e ansible_ssh_port=22
```

２回目以降は、playbook のまま

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml
```

２回目以降も、init タグの play が実行されますが、冪等性が確保されてれば問題なしかと。
ただ、deploy ユーザーは、init の play の中で、sudoers の設定が必要…

(init の順番とか間違うと、だれもリモートからログインできなくなりそう)